# If no lines found in .txt file print once

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having a problem with my code printing only once if a variable is not found in any lines. It does a great job printing the line if it is found, but if it isn't located, it's a complete mess.

The .txt file looks like this but a lot longer:

```
14312 Dog 
54314 Cat 
76543 Pig
53244 Chicken
52314 Monkey 
87465 Cow
```

Heres the code that I have

```
num = input(str('enter number:'))
with open("numbers.txt") as search:
    for line in search:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if num in line:
            print(line )
        if num not in line:
                print('hello world')
```

I think I understand the problem which is that the section that says:

```
if num not in line:
                print('hello world')
```

is searching all of the lines one by one and every time the user input isn't in a line, it's printing hello world. I need it to evaluate all of the lines and only print 'hello world' if it couldn't find any lines with the user input.

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds weird, but use a for...else clause:

```
num = input(str('enter number:'))
with open("numbers.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if num in line:
        print(line)
        break
else:
    print("No match!")
```

The else statement will only execute if the for loop never breaks. I assume that there will only be one match, however; if there are multiple lines you want to print, this solution will not work. Lastly, it is best to use `readlines()` to get a list of the lines, then parse them individually.

Comment: If they are (it doesn't seem that way?) please edit my post.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! I noticed that you have the 'lines = f.readlines()' line in there. Is there a reason I should have that if it works without it? (I'll mark this as solved but it's making me wait 5 min)

Comment: I just prefer to have a list of items. Makes it far easier to access the line later.

Comment: Oh I got you. The only reason why I didn't do that was because the file is about 40,000 lines long and I didn't know if it would be smart to load such a large list. I'm still very green with coding. I'll give this a shot because I'll actually be replacing the first print with a variable assignment so I can format the line result. Thanks!

Comment: @101arrowz check this out for your problem -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Answer (score 1):

Would be something like this:

```
num = input(str('enter number:'))
found = 0
with open("numbers.txt") as search:
    for line in search:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if num in line:
            print(line)
            found = 1
if found == 0:
    print('hello world')
```

Comment: Use a boolean instead. An int wastes space and is frankly very unpythonic.

Comment: It was an example to show the idea in a clear way, not a reason to downvote

Comment: This worked as well. I actually tried this solution once but with boolean and it didn't work. I think I messed up my indents? Can I mark both answers as a solution?

Comment: Sorry, but you can't. Normally the good idea is to mark the one given earlier as an answer, but if you prefer the other solution, you should mark the other one.

Comment: Mark the answer that works better for you as correct. Also, if you wanted to use a boolean, you would do `if found:`.

Comment: (an answer to deleted comment) I did not downvote anything, but had such a situation once. You can report it to the moderator. If there were more than few downvotes in the same time by the same account, it will be reversed.

Comment: Thank you for the info. It was quickly reversed, actually. Sorry for the accusation.

Comment: Even without boolean you can do `if not found` since `0` is Falsey.

Answer (score 1):

The other options work but here is another solution as well using a dictionary. It has to read through the file first but it is an instant lookup so after you read the file it will be fast.  This will in essence read the entire file into memory though. If you are only searching for a number (or `set` of numbers) once I would use the other solutions. If you are going to search the file multiple times (i.e. reading through the file multiple times) it would be better to just eat the memory to save the time.

```
num = input(str('enter number:'))
animal_numbers = dict()
with open("numbers.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Read each key and value from the file
        key, val = line.strip().split(' ')
        # Store that value (animal) for that key (the number).
        animal_numbers[key] = val

# If the number is in the numbers
# then we will print it
if num in animal_numbers:
    print("Animal: {} --- Number: {}".format(animal_numbers[num], num))
else:
    print("hello world")
```

Comment: He said the file is 40k lines long, so this would be a bit slower. However it's really elegant, so +1

Comment: I added a disclaimer. 40k lines isn't to much but it comes down to how many times he will read through the file. If he only reads the file to look for a number (or list of numbers) once this isn't worth it but if he reads it multiple times I would bite the bullet with memory to save time. Its always the trade off between memory and time.